# Public instance variable is visible in the first child but not in the second one

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, xamarin.forms

I have three classes, one of them (`ContentPage`) is built in the framework I use (`xamarin.forms`).

The `ContentPage` class definition

```
public class ContentPage : TemplatedPage{
    public View Content { get; set; }
}
```

The `ContentPageRequiresRegistration` class definition

```
public class ContentPageRequiresRegistration:ContentPage
{
    private static enumUserType userType;
    public ContentPageRequiresRegistration():base()
    {
        if(userType==enumUserType.unRegistered)
            Task.Run(() => this.LoadRegitrationPage()).Wait();

    }

    private async void LoadRegitrationPage()
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Registration(false));
    }
}
```

The `FillForm` Class

```
public partial class FillForm : ContentPageRequiresRegistration
{
    public FillForm(int formID){
        Content = new ....;
    }
}
```

The problem that appears is that `Content` in the `FillForm` class does not exist in the current context, even though it's defined public in the super class.

I tried to reach `Content` instance in `ContentPageRequiresRegistration` class and it didn't give me any error.

I tried also to use `base.Content` in `FillForm` class and it worked fine, but when I call it without `base` it gives me the error `The name 'Content' does not exist in the current context`.

Why is that happening even when `Content` is Public, and How can I use it in the `FillForm` class without need to use `base`?

Comment: `ContentPage ` or `Content ` ?

Comment: `Content`, which is the public instance of the class `ContentPage`

Comment: can you add it also? it seems missing in the code you posted.

Comment: `Content` does exist in the `ContentPage` class, and What I'm trying to do is using it from the objects of type `FillForm`.

Comment: Are you sure that the Xaml partial class is of "ContentPageRequiresRegistration" 
like does it start with 
< ContentPageRequiresRegistration>
... 
< ContentPageRequiresRegistration/>

Comment: @BraveHeart I changed the Xaml partial class to `ContentPageRequiresRegistration` and the error disappeared, Thanks a lot! If you posted an answer here I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change both partial classes to be of type `ContentPageRequiresRegistration`

1. In the Xaml part file you should have

   `< ContentPageRequiresRegistration> ... < ContentPageRequiresRegistration/>`
2. in C# partial class , it should extend
   `ContentPageRequiresRegistration` as you already doing like

   `public partial class FillForm : ContentPageRequiresRegistration
   {
       public FillForm(int formID){
           Content = new ....;
       }
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a method in the base class to retrieve your Content,

```
private View _content { get; set; }

public View getContent()
{
    return this._content;
}
```

Comment: I know that I can solve this problem by making a clone of `Content`, But why can't I use it directly from the `ContentPage` class's second child objects?